# Can the phrase 地铁 in Chinese taken to mean the Underground (地下铁) and the Overground (地上铁)?

Tags: difference

The phrase 地铁 was initially a contraction of the term 地下铁路 (underground railway). However, can it be also taken to mean 地上铁 (overground) in addition to 地下铁 (underground) as well as a collective term for both systems, which serve the same function in urban transport?

Answer (score 1):

Both 地铁 and 地下铁 are short for 地下铁路 (under-ground railroad). It can only mean subway, even though some subways have above-ground sections.

Above-ground railroads are simply called 铁路 (no such thing as 地上铁)

The railways that are serving urban areas (same as subways) are typically called 輕铁 (light rail)

Comment: (伦敦)地上铁 is the commonly-accepted Chinese term for the (London) Overground.

Comment: I actually cannot quite believe your answer does refer to actual usage of native speakers in a place like Berlin or Hamburg. These cities have two complementary systems, U-Bahn and S-Bahn, The U standing for Untergrund (underground) and the S for either Schnell (swift) or Stadt (city). In both parts the U-Bahn is predominantly underground while the S-Bahn is overground or elevated (dam or viaduct). Now German users of the system consistently say 'U' and 'S' to refer to the *systems*, not their built features, ...

Comment: ... although Hochbahn is OK where a line is elevated *but only if its the elevated U-Bahn*. Using Hochbahn for the elevated parts of the S-Bahn is wrong and will lead to confusion. I'd expected native speakers here to do the same and when I have occasionally overheard them I heard "物班" and "S班". My guess is that such an informed city dweller would explain others sth like "物班就是地鐵，地下和高架的都有吧，然後S班就是到郊外去的，同樣不管地上地下的" . I do the same when in say Paris (Métro, RER, Transilien) or any place that has a similarly interwoven fabric of many strands: speakers adapt to the local customs.

Answer (score 1):

The names of different railways in Taiwan:

地(下)鐵(underground railway/subway); (地面)鐵路(at grade railroad); 高架鐵(elevated railway); 高鐵(hi-speed railroad); 捷運(inner city shuttle railway). The latter two are often above ground (elevated).